# Document Library - Two documents with similar content

Tags: document, library

There is Document **A**, which is uploaded in SharePoint. Now we modify Document **A** and save it as Document **B**. When we try to upload Document **B**, the Edit form of document library is auto populating with Document **A** properties.

Is there a way to upload Document **B** as new document for which the edit form should be empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do so using the browser only. You can do it through code, but in browser, "save as" new document, will preserve metadata as well.

Comment: whether creating a new document and copying the content instead modifying the existing one will prevent meta data auto populating?

Comment: Copying content to a new document won't preserve metadata.

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind that is, that SharePoint-Metadata is also saved in the Document-properties itself (for MS-Office-file-types). This is not the case for any other types (eg. .pdf)

Comment: So in other file types only file name will be the criteria that decides whether it is an existing document or new document?